# WHM install dropbox automated server backup?

Tags: linux

is it possible to make automated backup on dropbox business account for my server ?

my server has over 100 website total backup size about 500GB

is there any tutorial or example for my request ?

Comment: Verify your TOS allows you to send data to a 3rd party like that, I certainly wouldn't host with you if it did. You can install dropbox on anything but it takes up 100% of the dropbox size unless you are specific about what it doesn't sync. Then you can put your WHM/CPanel created tarballs in that directory and have them uploaded to dropbox.

Comment: how to do that ? @AndrewDomaszek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever backed up to NFS mounts using the built in backup tools with WHM.  However, here's the first 2 results in Google for this subject, both look like they'll do what you're looking for:

http://www.cpbackup.info/dropbox-uploader/ 
https://encylia.com/2014/08/31/how-to-backup-your-cpanel-accounts-to-dropbox/